# How can I define a check constraint on a string length (Django)

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking to do the following:

```
 constraints = [models.CheckConstraint(check=Length('code')==5, name='code_length')]
```

It fails because the `check` argument needs to be a
[A Q object or boolean Expression that specifies the check you want the constraint to enforce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/)

I'm not seeing string length [field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) nor am I seeing a way to incorporate the [Length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Length) database function into a Q object argument. The only other option is a boolean expression (which is what I aimed at in my failed attempt above) but apparently this is an [API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression) that I have to implement.

I am new to Django and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the `Length` on a `CharField`:

```
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Length

CharField.register_lookup(Length)
```

and then define the constraint with the registered `__length` lookup:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(check=Q(code__length=5), name='code_length')
        ]
```

Comment: wow, this is really nice. 9 minutes till I can accept. where in a project would you place these types of monkey patches?

Comment: @naftalimich: you can place it at the top of the `models.py` where you are defining the constraint.